# How do I remove associative array from javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative

I found the way to delete an item of associative array by :

```
delete array['knownkey'];
```

but what about delete the whole associative array,I mean just like empty an normal array:

the way to empty an normal array is [I found on the google]:

```
array = []  //or
array.length = 0
```

So,the associative array has the way to empty or remove the all items at once ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
assoc_array = {};
```

Should set `assoc_array` to an empty object (aka associative array in JavaScript).

Thanks to garbage collection, there is no real need to empty an existing object. You just go get a new one.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this will NOT empty an existing object, but create a new (empty) one. Any references to the old one should still see the old data.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
array = {}
```

..?